# Sin without knowing

Tags: sin

[image][image]

So it is said if you say “I swear on this on that“, “I swear on moms life and that“, we have committed shirk but I didn’t knew about this before I only just found it out. I want to know will this count because I have done it before without knowing that it’s shirk and that will it be counted.

Answer (score 2):

Allah is the most merciful and the most knowing, it is okay to commit shirk before knowing it was a shirk. My advice is that you shouldn't repeat the mistake and insyaAllah you will be forgiven.

Answer (score 1):

Specially if you broke a promise you should obey this ayat.

> Allah will not impose blame upon you for what is meaningless in your
>   oaths, but He will impose blame upon you for [breaking] what you
>   intended of oaths. So its expiation is the feeding of ten needy people
>   from the average of that which you feed your [own] families or
>   clothing them or the freeing of a slave. But whoever cannot find [or
>   afford it] - then a fast of three days [is required]. That is the
>   expiation for oaths when you have sworn. But guard your oaths. Thus
>   does Allah make clear to you His verses that you may be grateful.
>   [5:89](https://quran.com/5/89)

The intention that you have in your hearth when you do that surely matters according to the follow ayat. (Specially Allah, and you, know better than us the severity of the potentially commited shirk)

> Allah will not call you to account for thoughtlessness in your oaths,
>   but for the intention in your hearts; and He is Oft-forgiving, Most
>   Forbearing. 
>   [2:225](https://quran.com/2/225)

Fear Allah, follow His teachings, and I hope He will forgive you.